# HTACCESS Redirect all domain except two files

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My actual htaccess redirect my complete old site to my new site, I want to redirect all domain but except two file .php (protectetfile1.php and protectedfile2.php).

This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^olddomain.org [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^olddomain\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(protectetfile1|protectetfile2)\.php [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: EXCELENT htaccess!, if you want to add more files you can keep adding |

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can put more files with pipe symbols (OR).