# redirect all older site page except certain file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use this below code for redirect old site to new . all thing work but I want one page (php) not direct to new site . I test all way in this site and google but no way work !

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com [NC]
```

this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964045/htaccess-redirect-all-domain-except-two-files) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414015/redirect-site-with-htaccess-but-exclude-one-folder) not work for me :( . I want only jrequest.php in root folder not redirect to new site . sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude the file, put the following condition above your rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !filename\.php$
```

Your htacess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !new.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !filename\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i tested this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !jrequest\.php$  in line 2 but not work

Comment: sorry but still all page redirect to new domain